# How do I set custom image as background not inside drawable folder

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap, drawable

in my app, i need t create a way for user to select image file(jpg/png) from their gallery/sd card and make that image as a background image in my activity layout.can someone please show me a way to do this?

I have a Button and ImageView. After clicking it,User may able to choose image file from his Gallery and then selected image should set as background of the ImageView. i tried some of the questions asked by other people here.Doesn't working for me

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

use following in activity

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                //OI FILE Manager
                filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(filemanagerstring);
layout.setBackgroundDrawable( d )
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i need to let user choose image,from opening gallery and let him choose image.then if its bigger than display size,crop image to match display size

Comment: @VishwaMadushan I have updated it

Comment: Thanks.I'll check this and get back to you

Comment: Thanks @jafarbtech it works.

ut can i ask for something more? how can i set the selected wallpaper as background for ImageView or Layout?